# Copying WordPress to xampp: unable to connect after restoring database

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I am trying to copy a website from a live server to a local server using xampp. I have copied the WordPress files over from the server to the xampp htdocs file. I named the folder where they are held "mysite". However, when I restore the MySQL database and connect to it using `wp-config.php` trying to connect to any webpage on the site (http://localhost/mysite) gives the browser's default "can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost" message (on Firefox it shows a dinosaur struggling to connect two cables). I do not receive any other error messages.

The xampp server is running MariaDB ver 10.1.38 and PHP version 7.3.3
The live server is running MySQL ver 5.6.43 and PHP version 5.6.30

Is there any way to copy the files over so the website can function as it does on the live server? Or, at the very least, figure what is causing problems?

My first approach was to just copy the files over and restore the database. Could not connect to server once all files were set up.

I also tried setting up a blank WordPress site attached to a new database. This website worked. I installed all the updates and plugins from the site on the server with no problems. I have even tried connecting to a premade empty website with no plugins installed. However, every time I restore the database, the same problem occurs.

I have tried restoring databases using compatibility mode for MySQL40 and MySQL323 and neither have worked. I have also used the following SQL to set the hyperlinks in the database:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://example.com/wordpress', 'http://localhost/mysite') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://example.com/wordpress', 'http://localhost/mysite');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://example.com/wordpress','http://localhost/mysite');

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'example.com/wordpress', 'http://localhost/mysite');
```

The website works well on the server. It's just a basic WordPress website. I haven't been able to find any problems. However, all my attempts to copy over content to the xampp server result in a website that does not even display on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your **htaccess** file for the rewrite rule, if not This may occur by forcing SSL [https] via some plugin, verify and remove Force SSL on Database, wp-config.php or plugins levels.